# String comparison doesn't give the intended result with recognized speech data

Tags: python, speech-recognition

ok, so I had this code to run speech recognition and gather an utterance. then wanted to check that with a word that is already saved in a database.

```py
def recog():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    print("Speak Now:")
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio_data = r.listen(source)
        try:
            print("recognizing")
            recog.result = str(r.recognize_wit(audio_data, key="XDAYDVOGVTRP652K6TAWOWQR73WHJY6S"))
            print(recog.result)
            return recog.result
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print('Recognition error')
```

I've used this code segment below to retrieve the word needed to compare with.

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect('VIT.db')
c = conn.cursor()
post_ac = "select ans from ansc where id=" + str(i)
c.execute(post_ac)
conn.commit()
records = c.fetchone()
print(records)
print_c = ''+str(records)
conn.close()
```

Then I've used an if statement to check if they match

```py
if print_c == recog():
    print("Correct")
else:
    print("Incorrect")
```

but this code always gives me "correct" as the answer. What have I done wrong and how can I improve my code? I'm fairly new to python and tkinter, so excuse my mistakes.
p.s: fyi the data is retrieved successfully and correctly from the database and also from the recognition. I'm having the trouble with comparison is all.

Comment: What's the value of `print_c` and the value of `recog()`?

Comment: Why loop through the `records` even though `record` is just a single value

Comment: @AaronKeesing `print_c` is retrieved from the database, there are few words stored there. As for `recog()` it return the recognized speech data.

Comment: @CoolCloud Sorry if it's wrong, but I think I had to do it to get it as a string so I can compare

Comment: What I meant was what are the actual values of `print_c` and `recog()` because that will help indicate why the string comparison fails.

Comment: Also, if you change the code you should edit the original code in the question and not simply append the new code to the question. It's less confusing that way.

Comment: @AaronKeesing oh, my bad.. Well for an instance I saved 'home' as the value for `print_c` and it did recognize what I said as 'home; in `recog()`. So both values were 'home for an instance, but when I said another word, for example 'run' it recognized it for `recog()` as 'run'. Yet it returned the answer as 'correct' nonetheless after comparing with 'home' that is saved in `print_c`

Comment: @AaronKeesing Sorry, new to this stackoverflow thing. I've changed it in the question. Thank You

Comment: It is a certainty that if they are equal, python will recognize them as equal. If python says they are unequal, then they are. You need to use a debugger or print statements to verify the contents, length, and type of the data. Perhaps there's a leading or trailing space in one or the other. Or perhaps one is a string and one is something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a while I kinda figured out what's wrong and I've changed the code. All this time it was comparing

> 'string'

instead of

> string

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('VIT.db')
c = conn.cursor()    
post_ac = "select ans from ansc where id=" + str(i)
c.execute(post_ac)
records = c.fetchone()
print_c = str(records[0])
print(print_c)
```

so all I had to do was change `print_c = ''+str(records)` into `print_c = str(records[0])` , so it will compare correctly in the if statement. Thanks for anyone tried to answer and hope this helps for anyone needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `print` statements are backwards, so it has actually been telling you 'incorrect' for everything. You are also only loosely comparing the 2.

```
# '==' instead of 'in'
if print_c == recog(): # consider 'home' is IN 'homestead', but they aren't the same
    print("Incorrect") # shouldn't this be 'Correct'
else:
    print("Correct")   # ..and this 'Incorrect'?
```

None of your question has anything to do with `tkinter`. You can remove that tag.

Comment: ok, I've changed the code, but it still gives me the same answer for every comparison. But its 'Incorrect' this time for all.

Comment: @Naveedh ~ right, that's exactly what I said. I have no idea why your strings don't compare, but at least now, when you get it to work the strings will be absolutely equal and your print wont be lying to you.